# How to remove the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need some help (under the code you can see what I need)

here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="elementnr">
<button onclick="theFunction()">Remove it</button>
<p id="theElements"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var cars = ["Bentley", "Ferrari", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini"];
document.getElementById("theElements").innerHTML = cars;

function theFunction() {

    delete cars[3];
    document.getElementById("theElements").innerHTML = cars;

}
</script>
```

Right now this code when you click the button it removes the 3rd element(Mercedes) because we gave that function but i wanted to know if there's any way to edit the code so when i type the number 4 in the textbox and click the button it removes the 4th element or if i type 2 on the textbox and click the button it removes the 2nd element etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could read 'value' property of Input HTML element.

Using `delete` operator on an Array element in JS does not remove given element, but sets its value to `undefined`, thus array's length remains the same and it can lead to many bugs.

Usually `splice` function is used to remove something from an array in JavaScript.

```js
var cars = ["Bentley", "Ferrari", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Lamborghini"];
var carsList = document.getElementById("carsList");
var elementIndex = document.getElementById("elementIndex");

function removeElementByIndex() {
    cars.splice(elementIndex.value,1);
    setHtml(carsList, cars);
}

function setHtml(node, content){
  node.innerHTML = content;
}

setHtml(carsList, cars);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="elementIndex">
<button onclick="removeElementByIndex()">Remove it</button>
<p id="carsList"></p>
```